# Storyboard.begin() throws an InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I am not sure what is going on here. I am following the example provided by Microsoft. Everything is done on the back end because I need to decide if you user should enter stuff into a text field or should the text field value be displayed as normal text. The code is as follows:

```
            nameInput.Name = "inputName";
            nameInput.Text = "Journey Name";
            nameInput.KeyUp += onNameInput;

            ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
            animation.From = Colors.Blue;
            animation.To = Colors.White;
            animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, nameInput);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty));
            storyBoard.Children.Add(animation);
            journeyStackPanel.Children.Add(nameInput);
            ClockState state = storyBoard.GetCurrentState();
            storyBoard.Begin(); //<---Crashes here
```

I am following the

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672995(v=vs.95).aspx
```

example. I am not sure what is going on, unfortunately the debugger does not spit out any more information. Maybe I am missing a step? I am sorry that I am being a little vague but this is all the information I have on the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate this problem on the latest WP8 SDK, with the following error message generated:

> ColorAnimation cannot be used to animate property Foreground due to
>   incompatible type.

I believe this is because you're trying to change the Foreground property of the TextBox to a Color object, but Foreground is actually a Brush object, hence the Type Mismatch error. Instead, you have to change the Color property of the Foreground object.

Try this instead:

`Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(Foreground).(Color)"));`